# same version of firefox (v12) on two different computers displays fixed-width float differently

Tags: firefox, css-float

My float breaks on ONE person's Firefox (v.12) on a Windows machine (that I'm aware of)... Same version of Firefox on Windows displays fine on other machines.

Simplified breakdown of layout: Two container divs containing two floated fixed-width divs:

```
<div id="frame" style="width:942px; display:block"> <!--extra 2 px to accommodate border on interior div -->

 <div id="frame_content" style="width:940px; border: 1px solid; display: block">

  <div id="column_left" style="width:626px;float:left;"></div>

  <div id="column_right" style="width:314px;float:right;"></div> <!-- combined width of floated divs = 940 -->

 </div>

</div>
```

Adjusting the width of column_right to 313px fixes, but there is a 1px gap between the columns.

At my wit's end - because it's just the one computer! Any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the zoom level different on each machine? I've seen something similar myself where a floated element was wrapping onto a new line at certain zoom levels. Try pressing ctrl 0 on the affected machine to reset zoom to 100%

Comment: OMG ... yes that fixed it. Is there a way to force a person's browser to start at 100%? I didn't know the zoom setting could break a layout like that.

Comment: Yeah... it was a surprise to me too! I don't think it's possible to force the zoom level as it's an accessibility feature - the only way I can think around this is to either set the wrapping div to display:inline-block without a fixed width or to keep it as display:block but increase the width by 1px. I think this is only a problem at certain zoom levels too - if you click ctrl + to zoom in, you should see it looks fine at some levels and not others... annoying!!

Comment: Actually - just realized "frame_content" didn't even have the width specified in my css... changing it to 100% or 940px fixed the the layout at all zoom levels ... yayz! Thank you so much!

Comment: @trymor the reason zoom can break "pixel-perfect" layouts like this is that the widths all become non-integers, have to get rounded, and after rounding might no longer add up correctly.